# How to configure Eclipse for PyDev? Python doesn't appear in Preferences window

Tags: python, eclipse, plugins, configuration, pydev

I'm trying to install PyDev in Eclipse 3.6 on Windows 7.

I have Python 2.7 successfully installed.  I installed PyDev through Eclipse, and restarted.

When attempting to configure Eclipse to find my installed Python, (`Window -> Preferences`) the list that appears does not contain Python.  (See image below.)

If I go back to `Help -> Install New Software` to check what has been installed, PyDev appears as having been installed.

I've tried quitting Eclipse and opening again, with no change.  I tried uninstalling PyDev, and re-installing, with no effect.  Any ideas how to get Eclipse to see PyDev?

[image: alt window-should-display]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's an issue when installing plugins under Windows 7 with UAC (User Access Control) active. You need to run as administrator. Read [my blog post](http://blog.zvikico.com/2010/08/eclipse-plugin-installation-and-windows-user-access-control.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks much.  I opted to move Eclipse out of Program Files.  Wish I could give multiple upvotes.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Make sure you vote for the bug mentioned in my post. We want to get it fixed...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with interpreters not seen for pydev/python.

I followed the link1 below, I had to use the PyDev 3.2.0.zip file and install it with 7zip in the dropin folder, for my system it is:
"eclipse-SDK-3.5.2-win32-x86_64__classicversion\eclipse\dropins" folder. (if you just right click to unzip (not using 7zip) in the dropins folder, you get the 0x80010135 Path too long error).
Then I had to reboot my windows 7 64bit pc to see the pydev/python interpreters.
Then follow link2 and watch derek banas python online videos where he goes over the installs and tutorials.

link1: http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html
then at the bottom of the page select
http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html

Note: I also had to use the unzip trick for other eclipse updates ...